# Redirect to previous page in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url, session, redirect

I want to add a redirection URL to my login forms action (as a query) in login page, so after loging-in, one can visit the previous page he or she was surfing.

First I thought about using Zend Session and save the url of each page in a variable. but I read in the documentation that it has overhead. So, is there a better way to do so? or is there an other way to use zend session with no overhead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you need to grab the original url for the redirection.
You can do that by the Zend_Controller_Request class via:

```
$url = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

or simply by:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then, the tricky part is to pass it through the user request. 
I recommend to use the library Zend_Session, despite using a POST parameter is also legitimate:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Your-Namespace');
$session->redirect = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Please note that the address we kept includes the base path.
To redirect the client in the controller class, disable the option 'prependBase' to lose the base path insertion:

```
$this->_redirect($url, array('prependBase' => false));
```

Comment: Also one can serialize request object: `$session->redirect  = serialize($this->getRequest())`. Actually this is the solution I'm using now, after one year;)

Comment: serializing request object preserves all received data like POST datas.

Comment: @Morteza M. Where (or when) do you reconstruct the request with your method? Plugin?

Comment: @Julian Whenever you like! for example I serialize request when user post data that requires privileges. After redirecting user to login page and after he logs in successfully, I unserialize his saved request and process it. Yes you can do that in a plugin.

Answer (score 9):

What I have found as a simple method to accomplish this is just to have a hidden field in your login form.

Now, im not sure if your login form is a generic HTML element or is actually an instance of `Zend_Form`, but if its an instance of `Zend_Form`, you could simple add the following:

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'return', array(
        'value' => Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(),             
            ));
```

Then in my authentication script, like the comment above, I have a simple redirect that uses the value passed in to return them to the same page.

```
$this->_redirect($this->_request->getPost('return'));
```

Obviously in these two examples, they are just written to compact the code and probably do not represent the best way to accomplish it. The two methods using the `getRequest()` in my code are actually not embedded in the `redirect` or the `addElement`, but for example purposes I just slid them in there.

The answer above will obviously work as well, unless you have some massive page redirection going on. The main reason I am running mine this way right now is because not all of my forms are running in `Zend_Form` and its also nice being able to change the value of the hidden `return` input text box for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Jesta,
I prefer Jesta Answer. because am doing lots of routing, forwarding, preDispatch functions and so on!!! Thank you anyway. I wait for more answers.

Comment: The problem with this solution is data loss. Scenario: User logs in to the application and loads a form. he starts filling the form. meanwhile, session expires and he need to login again. when he submits the form, using this solution, his posted data are lost.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the same thing that Jesta is doing in his answer, but I added the following functions to my "MW_Form" class - which is a superclass of all my forms - easy enough to `$form->trackReferrer($this->getRequest());` from the controller with any form.  The getReferrer() function takes a "default" argument (which if the user has REFERER headers disabled, or there is no referrer - your going to want a default place to redirect back to)

```
  /**
   * Adds a form element named "referrer" and sets its default value to either
   * the 'referrer' param from the request, or the HTTP_REFERER header.
   *
   * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request 
   * @return MW_Form
   * @author Corey Frang
   */
  public function trackReferrer(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
    $this->addElement('hidden', 'referrer');
    $this->setDefault('referrer', 
      $request->getParam('referrer', 
        $request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')));
        // HTTP_REFERER not HTTP_REFERRER - grrr HTTP spec misspellings

    // use no decorator for the actual form element
    $this->referrer->setDecorators(array()); 

    // use our custom "referrer" decorator to stick the hidden before the <dl>
    $decorators = $this->getDecorators();
    $this->clearDecorators();
    foreach ($decorators as $class=>$decorator)
    {
      if (substr($class,-5) == '_Form') {
        $this->addDecorator('Referrer');
        $added = true;
      }
      $this->addDecorator($decorator);
    }
    if (!$added) $this->addDecorator('Referrer');

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the referrer field if it exists.
   *
   * @return string | false
   * @param mixed $default The value to return if referrer isn't set
   * @author Corey Frang
   **/
  public function getReferrer($default = false)
  {
    if (!isset($this->referrer)) return $default;
    $val = $this->referrer->getValue();
    if ($val) return $val;
    return $default;
  }
```

The Decorator Used - gives you the added benifit of not using up any rows in the `<dl>` created by zend_form:

```
class MW_Form_Decorator_Referrer extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract  {
  /**
   * Attaches the standard "ViewHelper" decorator for the 'referrer' element
   * prepended on the content
   *
   * @return void
   * @author Corey Frang
   **/
  public function render($content)
  {
    $form = $this->getElement();
    if ($form instanceOf MW_Form)
    {
      $referrer = $form->referrer;
      if ($referrer)
      {
        $decorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper(array('placement'=>self::PREPEND));
        $decorator->setElement($referrer);
        return $decorator->render($content);
      }
    }
    return "Error - No Referrer Found".$content;
  }
}
```

Example Usage (from a controller):

```
$form = $description->getEditForm();
$form->trackReferrer($this->_request);
if ($this->_request->isPost())
{
  if ($form->process($this->_request->getPost()))
  {
    return $this->_redirect($form->getReferrer('/page'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Gnarf looks nice. But in which file does the "trackReferrer" function go? What type of class is it? Is it a helper or what?

Comment: It's in my `My_Form` class which extends `Zend_Form` and all my forms extend from this....

Answer (score 3):

I have a predispatch hook in plugin for authorization. In it if (and only if) user needs to be logged I save the request URI to session and after logging in I redirect there. There is no overhead except when redirecting to login form. But that's a case where overhead is no problem. :)

```
if(!$auth->hasIdentity()){
  $this->_insertLastUrlToSession();
  $this->redirect('/index/login');
} else {
  //no overhead
}
```

Comment: Thank you all,
So, I will use new Zend_Session_Namespace instead of Zend_Session::start() in _insertLastUrlToSession helper,ha? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I see this already has an answer, but i'd like to throw mine in too, just as a different way to skin the cat sort of deal, using static methods.

```
class App_Helpers_LastVisited {
    /**
     * Example use:
     * App_Helpers_LastVisited::saveThis($this->_request->getRequestUri());
     */
    public static function saveThis($url) {
        $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
        $lastPg->last = $url;
        //echo $lastPg->last;// results in /controller/action/param/foo
    }

    /**
     * I typically use redirect:
     * $this->_redirect(App_Helpers_LastVisited::getLastVisited());
     */
    public static function getLastVisited() {
        $lastPg = new Zend_Session_Namespace('history');
        if(!empty($lastPg->last)) {
            $path = $lastPg->last;
            $lastPg->unsetAll();
            return $path;
        }

        return ''; // Go back to index/index by default;
     }
}
```

This doesn't run all the time, only on a need to basis.

That's the whole code, part of my blog post here (http://hewmc.blogspot.com/2010/08/simple-way-to-store-last-visited-url-in.html)

Comment: Thank you. I read your blog post and this answer. you know, accepted answer in this question is really simple when using forms in the case application doesn't use sessions at all. but it is usual for web applications to use sessions, so adding another key/value pair to store previous url doesn't make sense and your answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very kind of you. And thanks for visiting my blog, which I normally have ahem, no visitors :) . Actually I have updated that blog post, but only that my attitude is more inclusive of other use cases, the code is not changed. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

This Zend framework plugin allows you to save current and last qualified url and  filter out unwanted urls. feel free to use and comment:

```
<?php

class Plugins_PageLog extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();
        $params=$request->getParams();

        // to grap urls that are in default module, not in auth controller, and not an error url 
        $controller2= Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        if ($controller2->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request) 
            && ( $module == 'default' || $module == NULL )
            && $controller != 'auth'
            && ( !isset($params['error_handler']))
        ) {

            // init 2 session variables: the current and last qualified url
            if (!isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) $_SESSION['redirect'] = '';
            if (!isset($_SESSION['last_visited_url'])) $_SESSION['last_visited_url'] = '';

            // tempurl is to save current qualified url temporarily to ensure current and last qualified url will not be same
            if (!isset($tempUrl)) $tempUrl = '';
            if ($_SESSION['last_visited_url'] != $_SESSION['redirect']) {
                $tempUrl = $_SESSION['redirect'];
                $tempParams = $_SESSION['redirect_params'];
            }

            // save current qualified url
            $_SESSION['redirect']=$request->getRequestUri();
            $_SESSION['redirect_params'] = $params;

            // to ensure there are no duplicated urls due to browser refresh 
            if ($tempUrl != $_SESSION['redirect']){
                $_SESSION['last_visited_url'] = $tempUrl;
                $_SESSION['last_visited_url_params'] = $tempParams;
            }
        }

        //echo '<pre>';var_dump($_SESSION['last_visited_url']);echo '</pre>';
        //echo '<pre>';var_dump($_SESSION['redirect']);echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to gnarfs answer, i modified it to making it validate - for those of you that get a kick of it.

```
$this->addDecorator(array('WrapClose' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'placement' => 'PREPEND', 'closeOnly' => true));
$this->addDecorator('Referrer'); 
$this->addDecorator(array('WrapOpen' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'placement' => 'PREPEND', 'openOnly' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HTTP_REFERRER header like this:

```
// str_replace is the easiest way to get rid of domain - u can also preg_replace it   
return str_replace("http://".Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getServer("HTTP_HOST"),"",Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getServer("HTTP_REFERER"));
```

Comment: It is not always available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a fan of passing variables via session you could try to get $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable in a safe way. Basically it checks if your referrer url  and matches with your server local name, and scheme (http/https).

```
class My_Tools
{   
    public static function doesUrlMatchServerHttpHost($url)
    {       
        $scheme = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getScheme();
        $httpHost = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getHttpHost();
        $needleUrl = $scheme.'://'.$httpHost.'/';
        if (strpos($url, $needleUrl) !== 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static function safelyGetReferrerUrl($default)
    {
        if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == false){
            return $default;
        }
        if (self::doesUrlMatchServerHttpHost($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == false){
            return $default;
        }
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
}
```

And then just

```
$referrerUrl = My_Tools::safelyGetReferrerUrl('/');
```

As default you can set local uri ('/')

Answer (score 0):

$this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));

Comment: It doesn't save state. And HTTP_REFERER is not always available.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure there is some built in method for doing this somewhere in ZF, but I'm lazy, so I did it this way:

Create your own *App_Controller_Action* class (create /library/App/Controller/Action.php). Extend all of your controllers off of this class

In each of my controllers, I call $this->_initAuth(), function pasted below:

```
protected function _initAuth()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity() && strcmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/auth/login') <> 0)
        $this->_redirect('/auth/login' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    else
        $this->_identity = $auth->getIdentity();
}
```

In my AuthController, I do the following to make sure my form points to the full url:

```
$uri = str_replace('/auth/login','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (strlen($uri) > 0)
    $form->setAction($this->_helper->url('login') . $uri);
else
    $form->setAction($this->_helper->url('login'));
```

If the login validates, then I do the following:

```
if (strlen($uri) > 0)
    $this->_redirect($uri);
else
    $this->_redirect('/');
```

Comment: obviously before your application goes live, you'll want to sanitize $uri, which I haven't done yet, once you know all possible accepted inputs