# Redirection to previous page after login

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is my login controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$view = new ViewModel();
$loginForm = new LoginForm('loginForm');
$loginForm->setInputFilter(new LoginFilter());
$error = array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password'
);

if ($request->isPost()) {
    $data = $request->getPost();
    $loginForm->setData($data);

    // echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;

    if ($data['email'] == '' || $data['password'] == '') {
        $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("Please enter username and password ! ");
    }
    else {
        if ($loginForm->isValid()) {
            $data = $loginForm->getData();
            $getid = $this->getMemberTable()->selectByid($data['email']);

            // echo "<pre>";print_r($getid);exit;

            if (!empty($getid)) {
                if ($getid->postal == 1) {
                    $userPassword = new UserPassword();
                    $encyptPass = $userPassword->create($data['password']);
                    $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()->setIdentity($data['email'])->setCredential($encyptPass);
                    $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
                    if ($result->isValid()) {
                        $session = new Container('User');
                        $session->offsetSet('email', $data['email']);
                        $session->offsetSet('user_id', $getid->id);
                        $session->offsetSet('user_name', $getid->first_name);

                        // Redirect to page after successful login

                        $session = new Container('base');
                        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                            $error['status'] = 'success';
                            $error['message'] = 'We got the posted data successfully.';
                        }
                        else {
                            $ref = $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
                            $redirectUrl = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('HTTP_REFERER', $ref);
                            $this->redirect()->toUrl($redirectUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                            $error['status'] = 'error';
                            $error['message'] = 'Invalid Email or Password';
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("Invalid Username or Password ");

                            // Redirect to page after login failure

                            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', array(
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                        $error['status'] = 'error';
                        $error['message'] = 'Your Account is Deactivated!';
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("Your Account is Deactivated!");

                        // Redirect to page after login failure

                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', array(
                            'action' => 'index'
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $error['status'] = 'error';
                    $error['message'] = 'Record Does Not Exits, Please Register!';
                }
                else {
                    $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("Record Does Not Exits, Please Register!");

                    // Redirect to page after login failure

                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', array(
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ));
                }
            }

            // Logic for login authentication

        }
        else {

            // $error['status'] = 'error';
            // $error['message'] = 'Invalid Email or Password';
            //                      // $errors = $loginForm->getMessages();

            $view->setVariable('loginForm', $loginForm);
            return $view;
        }
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonModel($error);
    }
    else {

        // Redirect to page after login failure

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', array(
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
    }
}

// $view->setVariable('loginForm', $loginForm);
// return $view;

return array(
    'loginForm' => $loginForm,
    'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages()
);
```

I want to redirect to previous page after login. Currently everyone gets redirected to home, which I have set. How can I achieve it so that my script in zend framework 2 redirects to the previous page.

For example :

I clicked on about-us tab and there is one link which requires login when i click to that login page appears but after login it moves to home page.I want to redirect to same abouts us page..

Comment: Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303558/how-can-i-redirect-to-previous-page-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect to previous page in zend framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303558/how-can-i-redirect-to-previous-page-in-zend-framework-2)